# Убрать сообщения cowplot из документа rmarkdown

Tags: r

Пишу документ при помощи rmarkdown, использую пакет cowplot для того, чтобы свести несколько графиков в одно изображение. При "связывании" документа в html, выходит сообщение такого вида:

```
## 
## ********************************************************
## Note: As of version 1.0.0, cowplot does not change the
##   default ggplot2 theme anymore. To recover the previous
##   behavior, execute:
##   theme_set(theme_cowplot())
## ********************************************************
```

Не знаю, как убрать это из финального документа, даже r echo = FALSE не помогает.

Comment: Может аргумент чанка message = FALSE?

Answer (score 1):

сообщения, судя по всему, выдаются при загрузке пакета:

```
> library(cowplot)
....
```

если да, то попробуйте обернуть загрузку двумя дополнительными обёртками: `suppressMessages()` и `suppressWarnings()`:

```
> suppressMessages(suppressWarnings(library(cowplot)))
```